# Sqoop export failing with NumberFormatException

Tags: export, teradata, sqoop

Not able to export data into teradata using sqoop for double values. I am getting NumberFormatException even if I have changed the datatype at teradata to string, I get NumberFormatException. I believe converting a string into a float or Integer results to NumberFormatException. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have also included map-column-java option in sqoop export to explicitly mention the datatypes for the columns to get exported.

I have a csv file with "|" delimiter and the sample data looks like below.

```
65.0|50.0|65.0|118.77
101.0|96.0|101.0|210.08
37.0|29.0|37.0|34.78
66.0|61.0|66.0|153.78
```

and my teradata table is created as below.

```
CREATE SET TABLE DB_NAME.TABLENAME(
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(20),
  col3 varchar(20),
  col4 varchar(20)
)
```

I have also tried having the datatype as decimal(10,5) and mentioned the map-column-java as "Double" for all the columns but I still get the same error.

From OP comment:

```
sqoop export --libjars /opt/cloudera/parcels/SQOOP_TERADATA_CONNECTOR/sqoop-connector-teradata-1.7c6.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/SQOOP_TERADATA_CONNECTOR/lib/terajdbc4.jar \
  --connect "jdbc:teradata://host_name/Database=database_name,CHARSET=UTF8" \
  --table table_name \
  --username username \
  --password password \
  --export-dir /path/to/directory \
  --map-column-java col1=Double,col2=Double,col3=Double,col4=Double \
  --input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
  --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
  --input-null-string '' \
  --input-null-non-string ''
```

Comment: Can you include the sqoop command? For example, did you specify --fields-terminated-by?

Comment: Yes I did infact. below is my sqoop command.  sqoop export --libjars /opt/cloudera/parcels/SQOOP_TERADATA_CONNECTOR/sqoop-connector-teradata-1.7c6.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/SQOOP_TERADATA_CONNECTOR/lib/terajdbc4.jar --connect "jdbc:teradata://host_name/Database=database_name,CHARSET=UTF8" --table table_name --username username --password password  --export-dir /path/to/directory --map-column-java col1=Double,col2=Double,col3=Double,col4=Double --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-null-string '' --input-null-non-string ''

Comment: Can you please ddit tye question and add the sqoop command to it. It is muvh easier for people trying to help you if they don't have to assemble the question by reading through all of the comments.

Comment: What about the input file? How was it prepared? Was it prepared on windows for example? If so, the line endings will not be \n. can you post a few lines of a hexdump of your sample file? Also, you mention that you tried using char instead of double for your sqoop command. What happened then?

Comment: Hi GMc, the input file was prepared using spark selecting those columns from a table and saving it as csv with delimiter as pipe.

Comment: And what about the second part of my question when you changed everything to Char instead of Double? What happened then? If everything (i.e. Teradata table and the sqoop job mapping) is Char/String, you should not see a number format exception.

Comment: I have created a different table with all columns as varchar in TD and converted all the source columns to String. Still I get the same exception NumberFormatException. This is all my question is about. My source and destination have String/varchar datatypes but it still gives me NumberFormatException.

Comment: There is probably something subtle that you are missing (and by not showing that variant of the scripts makes it impossible to answer the question). It does not make much sense that if your sqoop mapping is to String and the data type of your Teradata table is CHAR or VARCHAR that a conversion is occurring. Therefore it is hard to figure why you get a NumberFormatException when working with String + CHAR/VARCHAR. Can you post a transcript of your show table + the sqoop command as a single block of code? i.e. run bteq + show table, quit bteq then run sqoop and put the whole transcript here.

Comment: Hi GMc, I worked with the support yesterday and tried few options and one worked. I have to create columns with DOUBLE PRECISION datatype for the double datatype at source. Previously, I used Decimal(m,n) and it worked fine, so I haven't tried this option